# What book was about an astronaut stranded on an alien world where he keeps a video log?

Tags: story-identification, aliens

This was a book written in the last 10 years about an astronaut that becomes stranded on an alien world and keeps a video log of his life there until his death. The book was written as a post-mortem story when rescuers find the log.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ApocalypticLog